# OOP representation of data from a JOIN query

Tags: oop, design-patterns, orm

I have four tables: department (id, name), course (id, name), staff (id, name, dept_id) and staff_to_course (staff_id, course_id). I need to show how many people from each department have (and haven't) completed each course as well as an average for each department and a for each course:

```
       | Course 1 | Course 2 | Average |
----------------------------------------
Dept 1 |      20% |      30% |     25% |
----------------------------------------
Dept 2 |      10% |      40% |     25% |
----------------------------------------
All    |      18% |      33% |     25% |
----------------------------------------
```

I can do the SQL join query but I'm confused about how to properly use objects to represent the data internally.

I've currently got Course and Department objects but writing methods like `$course->percentComplete($dept_id)` feels kinda wrong and `$course->percentComplete('all')` feels even more wrong. The course average figure isn't a sensible property of a course instance object but putting it on the department object would mean duplicating the code across two classes which is definitely wrong.

I expect there's some basic OO principle I'm violating here but I can't see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the code in the Staff class in static methods.

For example...

```
public class Staff extends MyAbstractDB{

   // your attributes

   // your getter/setter

   public static List<Staff> listCompleted(Department dep){
     // here you should execute the sql query or use a criteria builder if you are using Hibernate
   }

   public static List<Staff> listCompleted(){
     // ...
   }

}
```

Could this solution work for you?

Comment: Thanks Fabrizio, but it seems to me using static methods in that way is essentially giving up on OOP and going back to functions.